# AWS Deployment issue Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS (In-place deployment)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy

i want to Host my website on AWS s3
but when i create code deployment  & i followed this url -> https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-code-vm/

showing this error ->   Deployment Failed
The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)

error Screen shoot -> http://i.prntscr.com/oqr4AxEiThuy823jmMck7A.png

so please Help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host your website on S3, you should upload your code into S3 bucket and enable Static Web Hosting for that bucket. If you use CodeDeploy, it will take application code either from S3 bucket or GitHub and host it on EC2 instances.

I will assume that you want to use CodeDeploy to host your website on a group of EC2 instances. The error that you have mentioned could occur if your EC2 instances do not have correct permission through IAM role.

From [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html)

> The permissions you add to the service role specify the operations AWS CodeDeploy can perform when it accesses your Amazon EC2 instances and Auto Scaling groups. To add these permissions, attach an AWS-supplied policy, AWSCodeDeployRole, to the service role.

If you are following along the sample deployment from the CodeDeploy wizard make sure you have picked **Create A Service Role** at the stage that you are required to Select a service role. 
[image]